# Use Serilog with Azure Log Stream

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core-2.0, serilog

I've been researching about how to use Serilog to write to Azure log stream. I found a few answers here too; for example, one answer was suggesting to log to a file in a specific folder (`home\LogFiles\http\...`), but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

I tried using [Trace](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-trace) and [Debug](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-debug) sinks, but I couldn't see my messages in Azure log stream.

To make matters even more confusing for me, even using `System.Diagnostics.Debug` or `System.Diagnostics.Trace` doesn't work either.

So, maybe two questions:

- How should I write to Azure log stream, in general?
- Is it possible to use Serilog infrastructure while also writing to the log stream?

It goes without saying that I have enabled "Diagnostic Logs" in my Azure App Service.

Any help is truly appreciated,

Thank you

Comment: Have you enabled the filesystem diagnostic logs? :) Diagnostic logs in Storage are not streamed.

Comment: Yes, I have enabled the file system logging

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [file sink](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file) has been reported to work correctly with the following configuration:

```
    .WriteTo.File(
         @"D:\home\LogFiles\Application\myapp.txt",
        fileSizeLimitBytes: 1_000_000,
        rollOnFileSizeLimit: true,
        shared: true,
        flushToDiskInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
```

There are a few subtleties to watch - `shared:` and `flushToDiskInterval:` especially.

Comment: Thank you @Nicholas for your answer; unfortunately, I haven't had the time to test it. Just one question: I'm using `Serilog.Settings.Configuration`, and I was wondering how I can specify the `flushToDiskInterval` property you have provided in my `appsettings.json` file...?

Comment: @Farzad you can do it using the config like below `"Name": "File","Args": {
     "path": "d:\\home\\LogFiles\\rawLogs\\mw.log",
     "rollingInterval": "Day",
     "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] {SourceContext} {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}",
     "shared": "true",
     "flushToDiskInterval":  "0:00:02"
    }`