# How to setup Serilog with Azure Functions v4 correctly?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, serilog, .net-6.0, datadog

I want to use Serilog in an Azure Function v4 (.net 6) (the logs should be sent to Datadog). For this I have installed the following nuget packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.10.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging" Version="3.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Formatting.Compact" Version="1.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="4.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Datadog.Logs" Version="0.3.5" />
```

Below is the configuration in the Startup.cs class:

```
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
  builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
  
  //... adding services etc.

  Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Worker", LogEventLevel.Warning)
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Host", LogEventLevel.Warning)
    .MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Error)
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Function", LogEventLevel.Error)
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Azure.Storage.Blobs", LogEventLevel.Error)
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Azure.Core", LogEventLevel.Error)
    .Enrich.WithProperty("Application", "Comatic.KrediScan.AzureFunctions")
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .WriteTo.DatadogLogs("XXXXXXXXXXX", configuration: new DatadogConfiguration() { Url = "https://http-intake.logs.datadoghq.eu" }, logLevel:   LogEventLevel.Debug)
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .CreateLogger();

  builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider>(sp => new SerilogLoggerProvider(Log.Logger, true));

  builder.Services.AddLogging(lb =>
  {
    //lb.ClearProviders(); //--> if used nothing works...
    lb.AddSerilog(Log.Logger, true);
  });
```

Basically logging works, but all log statements are written twice (with a few milliseconds difference, Datadog and Console).

[image]

Obviously I am doing something fundamentally wrong with the configuration. I don't use appsettings.json, the configuration of Serilog takes place exclusively in the code. I have scoured the entire internet and read just about every article on Serilog and Azure Functions. On Stackoverflow I also read virtually every question about it and tried all the answers. Unfortunately, so far without success.

SO-Questions for example:
[Use Serilog with Azure Log Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49744852/use-serilog-with-azure-log-stream)
[How do I use Serilog with Azure WebJobs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67321356/how-do-i-use-serilog-with-azure-webjobs)
[Serilog enricher Dependency Injection with Azure Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64025879/serilog-enricher-dependency-injection-with-azure-functions)
https://github.com/hgmauri/sample-azure-functions/blob/main/src/Sample.AzureFunctions.DotNet31/Startup.cs

Is there any example for setting up Serilog with Azure Functions v4 / .net 6?

Thanks a lot for the help!
Michael Hachen

Comment: Perhaps I'm being dumb, but isn't the log written twice because that's what you've told it to do? `.WriteTo.DatadogLogs(...).WriteTo.Console()`

Comment: I have the same configuration in a .net 6 web api => `WriteTo.Console(...)` and `.WriteTo.DatadogLogs(...)` without any duplication of the error logs. So if there is not something completely different between a .net 6 web api and a .net 6 Azure Functions this should not cause the duplication of the logs. And I removed the `WriteTo.Console(...)` - still duplicated logs.

Comment: Just wanted to say: Great question with evidence of prior attempts/research.  Well done!

Comment: Great question, helped me to quickly setup my serilog logging for azure functions :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Got it! After replacing all `ILogger` with `ILogger<T>` and removing the line `builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider>(sp => new SerilogLoggerProvider(Log.Logger, true));` everything worked as expected.

Startup.cs

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
          .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
          .MinimumLevel.Override("Worker", LogEventLevel.Warning)
          .MinimumLevel.Override("Host", LogEventLevel.Warning)
          .MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Error)
          .MinimumLevel.Override("Function", LogEventLevel.Error)
          .MinimumLevel.Override("Azure.Storage.Blobs", LogEventLevel.Error)
          .MinimumLevel.Override("Azure.Core", LogEventLevel.Error)
          .Enrich.WithProperty("Application", $"xxxxx.AzureFunctions.{builder.GetContext().EnvironmentName}")
          .Enrich.FromLogContext()
          .Enrich.WithExceptionDetails(new DestructuringOptionsBuilder()
            .WithDefaultDestructurers()
            .WithDestructurers(new[] { new SqlExceptionDestructurer() }))
          .WriteTo.Seq(builder.GetContext().EnvironmentName.Equals("Development", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? "http://localhost:5341/" : "https://xxxxxx.xx:5341/", LogEventLevel.Verbose)
          .WriteTo.Console(theme: SystemConsoleTheme.Literate)
          .CreateLogger();
      
      builder.Services.AddLogging(lb =>
      {
        lb.AddSerilog(Log.Logger, true);
      });
```

Comment: could you please share some code on how you configure `Startup.cs` and wire it up. I believe you have use NON-isolated V4/net 6.

Comment: Agree. Showing Startup.cs, Host.json, any other configs (e.g. appsettings.json) and usage of the logger would really help others who have the same problem!

Comment: This setup writes double to the console. Did you ever find a way to remove the built-in console logger in Azure Functions?

Comment: For me, this configuration worked. Do you have another log configuration in appsettings.json?

Answer (score 5):

For those that got here because they can't properly config their logging in an azure function with the app insights sink this is what works for me:

```cs
private static void ConfigureLogging(IServiceCollection services)
{
   Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Information()
        .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
        .MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Warning)
        .MinimumLevel.Override("Worker", LogEventLevel.Warning)
        .MinimumLevel.Override("Host", LogEventLevel.Warning)
        .MinimumLevel.Override("Function", LogEventLevel.Warning)
        .MinimumLevel.Override("Azure", LogEventLevel.Warning)
        .MinimumLevel.Override("DurableTask", LogEventLevel.Warning)
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .Enrich.WithExceptionDetails()
        .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(
            TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault(),
            TelemetryConverter.Events,
            LogEventLevel.Information)
        .CreateLogger();
        services.AddLogging(configure => configure.AddSerilog(Log.Logger));
}
```

The example [here](https://github.com/serilog-contrib/serilog-sinks-applicationinsights#using-with-azure-functions) at the time of writing doesn't seem to work.
The logging scope doesn't get captured in the output.

Serilog Version: 2.11.0

Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights Version: 4.0.0

Linked example for the future:

```cs
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(MyFunctions.Startup))]
namespace MyFunctions
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider>((sp) => 
            {
                Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                    .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(sp.GetRequiredService<TelemetryClient>(), TelemetryConverter.Traces)
                    .CreateLogger();
                return new SerilogLoggerProvider(Log.Logger, true);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To set up `Serilog.ILogger` instead of `ILogger<T>` you can add Serilog as Singleton

```
builder.AddSingleton<ILogger>(Log.Logger);
```

instead of

```
services.AddLogging(configure => configure.AddSerilog(Log.Logger));
```

and then in the function inject `ILogger` from Serilog instead of `ILoggerFactory` and log as

```
_logger.Information("awesome log");
```

I run isolated function in .net7

Answer (score 2):

For a Functions v4/ Isolated .NET 7 version of this

```
builder.ConfigureServices((hostingContext, services) =>
{ 
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(config)
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .WriteTo.Console()
        .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault(), TelemetryConverter.Traces)
        .CreateLogger();

    services.AddLogging(lb => lb.AddSerilog(Log.Logger, true));
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
    services.AddInterventionCalculatorServices(config);//injecting my services
});
```

Gets you serilog with sinks for console and Insights.

You can also configure the default logger within the `hosts.json` file

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "Function.MyFunctionName.User": "Information",
      "Function": "Error"
    }
}
```

To remove duplicate messages (there may be a way to turn off console entirely from here, but I've not found one).

After this, you should only be seeing your serilog sinks and only 1 set of the important console messages.

Note that recent versions of Visual studio have had some issues with copying files on "F5" (latest patch `17.7.0 Preview 3.0` to VS Community is supposed to resolve this, but I'm not sure its 100%). Make sure to rebuild after changing your hosts.json file and to verify whats in your deployed folder to retain your sanity...